# Regex that captures all characters except "^"

Tags: regex, p-lang

I have the following **problem**:

- I want a regex to capture all characters in a paragraph that contains "#flashcard" and a string after a line break that starts with a "^" sign. E.g.,

`lorem ipsum #flashcard ^4599993`

- However, the regex should ignore/exlude the sign "^" itself. The result should be, e.g.,

`lorem ipsum #flashcard  4599993`

- I started with this regex

`((?:[^\n][\n]?)+) #flashcard ?\n*((?:\n(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*))+)`

- I tried all kinds of modifications but it always captured the "^" sign. E.g.,

`^(?!\^)(.*?)#flashcard:(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*)`.

**Solution**: A modification of this regex

`((?:[^\n][\n]?)+) #flashcard ?\n*((?:\n(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*))+)`

that ignores the "^" sign.

Thank you for any help & advise!

Comment: You can't cut a hole in the middle of a match.

Comment: `and a string after a line break that starts with a "^"`, where is the line break in `lorem ipsum #flashcard ^4599993` ?

Comment: You can use twice regex:
First time regex :  `/#flashcard.(.*?)$/i`   Second time regex: `/\^/i` for select ^ only

Comment: try this : `#(.*?).\^|\d`

Comment: Besides the missing newline in the example data, in the patterns that you added to the question there seems to be more going on than just matching a `^` after `#flashcard` Can you add some real life examples of paragraphs and would you also accept multiple capturing groups as a match, or a second replacement over the matched string?

Answer (score 0):

This could be your pattern: `/^(.+?#flashcard )\^(.+?)$/`

And then replace the matchings with: `$1$2`